# SurfaceView with OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

OpenGL ES 2.0 is implemented in a project that I have been working on with a couple shader components that define what a texture should look like after modifications from a Bitmap. The SurfaceView will only ever have a single image in it for my project.

While doing several different approaches and looking through code in the past 24 hours, just hoping for a quick response or two from the community.  Not looking for solutions, I'll do that research.

It sounds as though since we are using shaders, that in order to do scaling and movements in the texture based on touch events, that I will have have to use the Matrix utilities and OpenGL translations or movements with the camera to get the same effect as what is currently done within an ImageView.  Would this be the appropriate approach? Perhaps even modify the shader code so that I have some additional input variables?

I don't believe that I can use anything on the Android side that would get the same effect, such as modifying the canvas of the SurfaceView or altering dimensions of the UI in some other fashion that would achieve the same effect?

Thanks.  Again, solutions for zooming and moving around aren't necessary, just trying to get a grasp on intermixing OpenGL and Android appropriately for the task.

*Why does it seem that several elements in 1.0 are easier than 2.0; ease of use should improve between releases.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will need to use an ortho projection and adjust the extents to zoom. See [this](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/132061-help-with-orthographic-zoom) link here. To pan, you can simply use a glTranslatef.

If you would like to do this entirely in the pixel shader, you can use the texture matrix stack with glScalef and glTranslatef.

Comment: Aren't those functions however only available with OpenGL 1.0 / 1.1? Trying to be sure that I am not missing something when it comes to intermixing things with 2.0.

Comment: I assume that for this particular task, I would have to reference functions such as Matrix.translateM( ) and Matrix.scaleM( ) in their stead.  I'll plan on using this approach then, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, those are not valid for 2.0 but the functions you point to are. To answer your question about why 2.0 seems harder, certain decisions were taken in order to simplify driver development and bring it to parity with DirectX. Allowing implicit GL state access in shaders is not easy.

Comment: Ok.  Once again, thanks for verifying.  I'll have to start remembering matrix multiplications once again back from mathematics courses.  Or hopefully apply getMatrix( ) from ImageView and pass it along appropriately inside the Renderer.